# mail ,pdf icon images giving mirror impression in joomla

Tags: php, joomla1.5

IN joomla site ,
I made the replica of one joomla site.
Just took the data from ftp and put it onto another server,its working fine.
But the problem is when I click on mail or pdf icon images which are on  every pages  right top side ,its gives the mirror effect,
for eg:

```
subject:_____________________
but
result is
           ____________:subject
```

Comment: Is there a stylesheet that perhaps the cloned site can no longer access, and the styles are no longer being applied?

Comment: I am totally new .
I have very less knowledge of joomla. I just took the contents and upload it.

Answer (score 1):

use `<span style="float:left">subject:</span>`

please report if it's not working, then i'll go through another possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You may have an attribute on the `<table>` tag of the form with the attribute `dir="rtl"`, organizing cell from right to left.

Is it only on those forms or on the whole page (do you have in the HTML source a `<link>` with name like templace_rtl ?

You may search in your XML config files if you have a node `<rtl>1</rtl>` also, and set it to 0 to go back to occidental languages alignment.

Answer (score 0):

View the source code of your page and look for a line of code that looks something like this -

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mysite.com/assets/site.css" type="text/css" />
```

Copy the URL inside the "href" portion and paste it into your browser and see if you can see the file or if it gives you an "object not found" error. If it does, you'll need to go to your administrator panel, template manager, select your template, click "Edit HTML" and adjust the URL so that it points to the proper address.